# Trinidad Component

Tags: responsive-design, oracle-adf, trinidad

How can I make my application web responsive design that is already design for desktop PC using Trinidad Component in ADF 11g?

Is it possible for with Trinidad component design application that support web responsive design?

Answer (score 0):

Responsive design requires some form of tidy HTML but most importantly a style sheet.

Style sheets are no problem in Trinidad. See the [skinning](http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/devguide/skinning.html) documentation on how to customize your style sheet.

The HTML is a different story. If you are using Trinidad's core renderkit you will end up with a lot of tables. Not the best choice for responsive design. You could create your own renderkit... Never tried it, but I assume it's a lot of work.

If your application isn't too complex, you might might be able to pull it off just using skinning.